Prerequisites to learn/work on double copy theory and amplitude methods for gravity
I am a PhD student in classical gravity; specifically in BH perturbation and GW.
I am interested in learning about the double copy and the use of scattering amplitudes in understanding GW physics. I have taken QFT courses before, and I am familiar with path integral methods.
How should I go about learning double copy theory?

This may get you going: "The double copy was first observed in string theory. In the mid-1980s it was
found [2] that closed string tree amplitudes could be written as sums of products of
open string amplitudes. This is a non-trivial manifestation, at the level of physical
observables, of the factorization of closed string states into products of left- and right-
moving open string states. The low-energy limit of the string-theory double copy is the
field-theory double copy exemplified in (1.1)."

This review: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.01358, is excellent

Questions about prerequisites are often off-topic because they are opinion-based. I suggest asking only for references instead
